# Using Van-Kampen theorem to find a fundamental group

Tags: algebraic-topology

I would be grateful if someone takes a look at my solution to the following problem to see if it is correct. Thanks a lot for helping people even during the holidays.

Sorry, I have to delete the question due to some moral stuff.

Comment: I hope you know that your whole question can be still seen in the edit-history.

Comment: @DanielBernoulli, the OP is not searchable which is good. The question was once on a comprehensive exam, and I thought that I shouldn't share the solution with others unless it is not searchable.

Answer (score 4):

I assume that you want to get a comment on your proof.

Here it is: Your argument looks solid, but I don't understand, why you take $\pi_1(U)=\langle \alpha\rangle$ instead of $\pi_1(U)=\langle \beta\rangle$, because if you take away the point $x_0$ where $A,B,C$ are identified, an obvious deformation retraction in my opinion would retract $Z\setminus\{x_0\}$ to $D$. Then for $\phi\colon \pi_1(U\cap V)\to \pi_1(U)$ the image $\phi(\gamma)=\alpha^3$ is really evident by this deformation retraction.

All in all your solution is plausible.

Off topic: The knot $K$ should be a torus knot. :)

Comment: @DanelBernoulli, thanks man, I will edit my post. +1 for your clarification.